# JPA's EntityManager createQuery() vs createNamedQuery() vs createNativeQuery()

Tags: jpa

Can anyone please explain me the differences between following methods of JPA's **EntityManager**:

- `createQuery()`
- `createNamedQuery()`
- `createNativeQuery()`

And also explain to me in which cases we should use which method?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. CreateQuery: Used to create an [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language)
2. createNamedQuery: Used to define queries with name in mapping file or annotation [go to this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/)
3. createNativeQuery: Used to execute native/pure SQL queries [Example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Comment: except that "HQL" is nothing to do with JPA. JPA uses JPQL

Answer (score 69):

- **The createQuery** method is used to create dynamic queries, which are queries defined directly within an application’s business logic.
  Example:

  ```
  public List findWithName(String name) {
  return em.createQuery(
  "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName")
  .setParameter("custName", name)
  .setMaxResults(10)
  .getResultList();
  }
  ```
- **The createNamedQuery** method is used to create static queries, or queries that are defined in metadata by using the javax.persistence.NamedQuery annotation. The name element of @NamedQuery specifies the name of the query that will be used with the createNamedQuery method. The query element of @NamedQuery is the query:

  ```
  @NamedQuery(
  name="findAllCustomersWithName",
  query="SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.name LIKE :custName"
  )
  ```

Here’s an example of createNamedQuery, which uses the @NamedQuery:

```
    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager em;
    ...
    customers = em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomersWithName")
    .setParameter("custName", "Smith")
    .getResultList();
```

- **The createNativeQuery** Create an instance of Query for executing a native 
  SQL statement. here are some reasons to choice **createNativeQuery**:

  - Low level access, which means that you can optimize and handle the mapping by yourself; with SQL you actually access the database table while with JPQL you access the entity objects;
  - Maybe you do not want to learn JPQL if you already know SQL
  - You already have the queries written in SQL, and do not have resources/time to port them to JPQL

For more details visit those links:

[Creating Queries Using the Java Persistence Query Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html)

[JPA why use createNamedQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832755/jpa-why-use-createnamedquery)

[Why do we need to create native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288416/why-do-we-need-to-create-native-query)

Comment: Whilst this links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference. Otherwise a comment would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

`CreateQuery` is used to create an JPQLqueries

`createNamedQuery` is used to define queries with name in mapping file or annotation, example: `obj.createNamedQuery("entity.findbycode",Something.class)`

`createNativeQuery` is used to execute native/pure SQL queries.