# Postgres Query to JPA Conversion

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have a postgres query that i want to execute with JPA.

Can any one tell me how to right following query in jpa

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM "RECEIPT" Where "STATUS"='1'
        ) AS count1,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   "RECEIPT"  Where "STATUS"='1'
        ) AS count2;
```

This returns

```
count1 count2
11      11
```

In jpa i tried following.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT (SELECT count(*)  FROM SMSReceipt Where status='1' ) AS count1,(SELECT count(*)  FROM SMSReceipt Where status='8' ) AS count2 ");
```

But this is not working

Please suggest me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `createNativeQuery()` method to run plain sql

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT (SELECT count(*)  FROM SMSReceipt Where status='1' ) AS count1,(SELECT count(*)  FROM SMSReceipt Where status='8' ) AS count2 ");
```

`createQuery()` is used to run JPQL.

Also Check -[JPA's EntityManager createQuery() vs createNamedQuery() vs createNativeQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798493/jpas-entitymanager-createquery-vs-createnamedquery-vs-createnativequery)